# Magento 1.8 Allow Same Email for 2 or More Customer Accounts

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-account

I´m using **magento** as **POS for travel services**, so the `user only fills` in the `customer create account` and `my sale people finish the sale from backend`. 
Since sometimes we **have a family traveling togethe**r but all **contracts (for legal purposes) are individual**, however **most times one person is responsible for filling in the form** (`I´m using create account page for that`) and **paying**, `I have the same email for 2 or more customers`. 
And **here is the problem**, since **magento does not allow to create 2 accounts with same email**. 
Does anyone have an idea on how to allow it to create different accounts with same email address? 
(remember, I don´t allow customers to login to the system so it´s not a problem future password retrieve or login attempts).

Comment: Why do you need to create accounts? Magento offers guest orders. Since you are not using any other functionality of customer account other that email and name you could simply just make guest orders which have all those informations and only build a module that would scan orders for new emails and present them in customer-like fashion without actual customer accounts (if you need such listing).

Comment: This is because the POS system requires that the customer is registered so my sale people can finish the booking (checkout cart). And also, people need to confirm that their info is correct, than the sales person get the client info and proceed to checkout. So that´s why I can not use guest checkout (the customer is not the one that checkouts and the sales person can not input guest data).

Answer (score 0):

Changing Magento behaviour would be too complex.

I suggest that you create a custom entity (EAV if needed to). Following the guide here: http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/.

For example you can call the entity Traveller. Then in the frontend you create a form for customer to fill up their detail along with their booking preference.

Once you have that information in the backend you can create a guest order using the detail in the traveller table.

Comment: I´m not sure I understood this William, you are suggesting to create another table, another form and instead of geting data for customer table get from this customized one? Is that it?